# Combine rewrite conditions

Tags: nginx

I have to combine two rules in nginx:

(1) if host is not `www.host.de` redirect to www.host.de

(2) if the protocol is HTTP redirect to https

My current solution first changes to www and on the next request it changes to https. That means I do have multiple redirects.

I try to reduce it to one redirect. My rules:

```
server_name     .host.de;
set $wanted_domain_name www.host.de;

if ($http_host != $wanted_domain_name) {
  rewrite  ^(.*)$  $scheme://$wanted_domain_name$1;
}

if ($scheme != "https") {
  rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
}
```

I tried resolving this by using parameters for rewrite using variables ( therefore I asked to store regex expressions in a variable https://serverfault.com/questions/812670/store-regex-in-variable ).

How can I optimize the redirects, so that I will not have two client side redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `if`s.

Use separate server blocks.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com;
    # ... ssl stuff ...
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    # ... ssl stuff ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: The OP wanted the opposite. non-www to www. Still, the logic behind the solution is correct, assuming there are no other domains hosted alongside example.com .

Comment: @Pothi fixed. Still the method is the same

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, we can split the conditions into server blocks...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com;
    # ssl_certificate ...;
    # ssl_certificate_key ...;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    # ssl_certificate ...;
    # ssl_certificate_key ...;

    # do whatever stuff you wish here
}
```

The solution isn't as short as one would expect. But, it still does the job!

Comment: @Alexey-Ten beat me in answering first. Yes, we don't need "location" in the first two server blocks.